# Change the state of a react app via API of the same app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm working on a huge project where functionalities are divided into a separate react project.

Consider the following scenario
[image]

Here `BaseReactApp` is the wrapper app where every chunks will be merged. Now my problem is I want to interact with the state of `ReactApp1`(Showing in iframe - blue area) from the buttons shown below the iframe.

I'm thinking about the scenario whereby clicking on the Button1, some kind of API interacts with the ReactApp1 and changes the state of the application which is showing over there. But I'm not sure whether it will work or not.

I've tried to make a route in the ReactApp1 to change the state of the app and hitting that URL via Button1 but it is not working. I guess because of the context issue...

Kindly let me know how can I achieve such a thing.

P.S. - ReactApp1 is purely a react project. Mostly it will be hosted on a different location.

Comment: How is your project structure...? If both the projects are in one parent directory you can use redux at the root level and connect both the projects with root redux.

Comment: What if you include the inner app via a its root component instead of an iframe? That way you can pass props to it.

Comment: @Ashish mostly both the projects will be hosted on a different location.

Comment: @ChrisG If it was possible to integrate both the projects then probably this issue won't arrive.

Comment: Right, what about socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

So you either have a shared state which will live in `BaseReactApp` and connect all the other components to it or you could communicate with the `iframe` via [cross-document-messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

If your different modules URLs are all located on the same domains, you can use a state management framework (such as [redux](https://redux.js.org/), [mobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html), [diox](https://github.com/matthieujabbour/diox), ...) and make it communicate between your iframes leveraging on the **window.parent** (iframe to parent) and **iframe.contentWindow** (parent to iframe) properties to access your Store globally.